# (Java) Paypal authorizationCode without mSDK

Tags: java, paypal

For paypal's future payment the user gets an authorization code from paypal when he gives the consent to future payments.
This code is sent to our backend and we send it back to paypal in order to get an access token and a refresh token.
Is it possible to get an authorization code for future payments without the paypal mobile SDK in order to implement automated tests in Java?
I'm looking for something like [here](https://devtools-paypal.com/guide/openid/java?interactive=OFF&env=sandbox) but without interaction with any GUI.

Answer (score 1):

It's not possible to get an authorization code without the paypal mSDK (see https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-iOS-SDK/issues/348)